# Is there any open source project to config params for installation?

Tags: open-source, software-development

When know some famous software written by PHP, such as `WordPress`, `WHMCS` and other, when install the web software, there will appear configuration pages one by one.

[image]

So, I find this common point, is there any open source project for PHP code to implement this?